# An example of real analytic and periodic function

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find a real analytic and $2\pi$-periodic function $f(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>0$ on $(0,\pi) \cup (\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi)$ and $f(x)<0$ on $(\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2})$ and $f(x)=0$ at $0$. Could someone provide an example of such a function or an idea how to construct it?

Comment: What have you tried? Was this left as an exercise? If so, what did you learn from the preceding text? Etc.

Comment: @FShrike Well, I have tried to set this function explicitly on each of the intervals and then glue them together, but this idea did not lead to anything, because the glueing of two analytic functions requires some strong conditions. 
This is just a question, don't really know if there is an answer somewhere.

Comment: Well I mean you could take some kind of Fourier series... truncate it at a useful point. I’m not sure

Comment: @FShrike Fourier series of which function should i take that the series will satisfy all the conditions? I thought about it, but i don't know how to realize this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl; dr: The function $f(t) = (1 + \cos t + \sin t)(1 - \cos t)$, in purple, has the requested behavior.

[image: A real-analytic function with specified behavior]

---

One way to discover such a function is to consider the unit circle parametrized by $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t) =: (x(t), y(t))$.

To arrange $f(t) > 0$ on the circle in quadrants 1, 2, and 4 (i.e., for $-\pi/2 < t < \pi$ mod $2\pi$) and $f(t) < 0$ in quadrant 3 (i.e., $\pi < t < 3\pi/2$ mod $2\pi$), we're naturally led to consider $1 + x + y$ as a function on the plane. That explains the factor $1 + \cos t + \sin t$, blue.

To arrange $f(0) = 0$ without altering the existing sign behavior, it suffices to multiply by a non-negative function that vanishes if and only if $t = 0$ mod $2\pi$. The obvious choice is $1 - \cos t$, which explains the second factor, red.